Reading and writing files in Haskell results in "withFile: resource busy (file is locked)"
I am attempting to make a to-do list cli, and the program can save these tasks to a .txt file entitled tasks.txt, however, when I attempt to add new tasks or view the contents of the .txt file, it results in an error message: "tasks.txt: withFile: resource busy (file is locked)". To my knowledge, this problem is stemming from lazy evaluation with Haskell
-- Save tasks to a file
saveTasks :: [Task] -> IO ()
saveTasks tasks = writeFile "tasks.txt" (show tasks)

-- Load tasks from a file
loadTasks :: IO [Task]
loadTasks = do
    fileExists <- doesFileExist "tasks.txt"
    if fileExists
        then do
            content <- readFile "tasks.txt"
            return (read content :: [Task])
        else return []

-- Main program loop
main :: IO ()
main = do
    initialTasks <- loadTasks
    loop initialTasks

-- Command-line interface
loop :: [Task] -> IO ()
loop tasks = do
    putStrLn "Commands: add <task>, view, remove <index>, done <index>, quit"
    putStr "Enter command: "
    hFlush stdout
    command <- getLine
    case words command of
        ("add":taskName) -> do
            let updatedTasks = addTask (unwords taskName) tasks
            saveTasks updatedTasks
            loop updatedTasks
        ["view"] -> do
            viewTasks tasks
            loop tasks
        ("remove":indexStr) -> case reads (unwords indexStr) of
            [(index, "")] -> do
                let updatedTasks = removeTask index tasks
                saveTasks updatedTasks
                loop updatedTasks
            _ -> putStrLn "Invalid index" >> loop tasks
        ("done":indexStr) -> case reads (unwords indexStr) of
            [(index, "")] -> do
                let updatedTasks = markTaskDone index tasks
                saveTasks updatedTasks
                loop updatedTasks
            _ -> putStrLn "Invalid Index" >> loop tasks
        ["quit"] -> putStrLn "Goodbye!"
        _ -> putStrLn "Unknown command" >> loop tasks


Your code does not have a withFile?

It is also very "un-Unix" to read and write to the same file: it makes the data sensitive to for example a power outage. It is quite common to write to a different file, and when that succeeds, swap the target with the source.

checkOnExist; readFile is bad approach. What will be if after check file will be removed? More better approach is readFile; catchErrors. In your case it will be loadTasks = do {content <- readFile "tasks.txt" <|> pure ""; return $ read content; } or loadTasks = read <$> (readFile "tasks.txt" <|> pure ""). But using read here is also bad approach, instead use readMay etc.

The readFile :: FilePath -> IO String [Hackage] is indeed lazy, so it promises to read the file when the content is needed, it does not read the file itself (completely).
We can use seq [Hackage] to force evaluating the (length of the) list, before returning the list, which thus will read the file to the end:
loadTasks :: IO [Task]
loadTasks = do
  fileExists <- doesFileExist "tasks.txt"
  if fileExists
    then do
      content <- readFile "tasks.txt"
      length content `seq` return (read content :: [Task])
    else return []
That being said, I would advise not to write to the same file as you read from. Actually reading lazily is something that is often a wanted effect: it reduces the memory footprint, and allows streaming where the source file is read and processed in chunks, and thus the file is never fully loaded in memory.
Most Unix-like programs never write to the file they are reading from, for example by using sort < frm.txt > /tmp/to.txt you created a sorted variant in /tmp/to.txt, and when that succeeds, you move the /tmp/to.txt to the frm.txt. That way, if there is for example a power outage, you always have at least the full source file, or the sorted file. By writing to the same file, and thus trusting the data in memory, if there is a power outage, it is possible that the file contains no data, or only the first lines, thus essentially destroying data.

Technically, the problem is "lazy I/O" rather than "lazy evaluation".  Haskell uses lazy evaluation all over the place, but it doesn't cause unreliable behavior unless you use certain functions, like readFile, that use "lazy I/O".  It's this "lazy I/O" which allows the effects of lazy evaluation to be visible to the outside world and potentially causes strange out-of-order behavior, like a file you're trying to write still being locked from a previous read operation.
The readFile function, because it uses lazy I/O, opens a file for reading and unsafely returns control to the rest of the program before actually reading it.  It's only when the contents are evaluated that the file content actually gets read, bit by bit, as the contents are needed.  This provides the "illusion" that the entire file has been read, without having to read the file fully into memory. To maintain this illusion when you use readFile, you need to promise that the contents of the file will remain untouched until the entire contents have been read, which means running some kind of evaluation that goes all the way to the "end".
If you are using GHC 9.0 or later, there is an alternate function readFile' in System.IO that works like readFile without the lazy I/O.  (If you're using an older version of GHC, you can find readFile' in the extra package in module System.IO.Extra.)  This function reads the file to completion before returning. You can try to the following tests.  The first will fail with the error message you report.  The second will work fine:
-- fails with an error
main = do
  writeFile "locktest.txt" $ "abc"
  txt <- readFile "locktest.txt"    -- lazy I/O, file still open
  writeFile "locktest.txt" $ "def"  -- resource busy

-- no lazy I/O, so works fine
import System.IO
main = do
  writeFile "locktest.txt" $ "abc"
  txt <- readFile' "locktest.txt"   -- strict I/O, file will be closed
  writeFile "locktest.txt" $ "def"  -- works fine

Note that writeFile, unlike readFile, doesn't use lazy I/O. It only returns after the full file contents have been written, so using readFile' and writeFile should always be safe.
In a nutshell, you can safely use readFile' in all situations. The only downside is that it reads the entire file into memory as a String, which is a ridiculously inefficient representation of the file contents (typically 40 times the original file size).  If you need to process big files, you can use readFile, but you need to take precautions to make sure the file contents don't change until evaluation has forced the last bit of the file to be read.
